# AWS SQS Delete Batch Message, Error: TooManyEntriesInBatchRequest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to delete `AWS SQS` Batch messages at a time, it deletes first `10` messages of array chunk but not deleting 2nd chunk, throw error

> AWS.SimpleQueueService.TooManyEntriesInBatchRequest (client): Maximum
>   number of entries per request are 10. You have sent 12.

I am following these steps.

**I have array of 12 messages, and converted them into chunks like this**

```
$chunks = array_chunk($entries, 10, true); // make chunks of 10 items per array
```

---

**Chunk 1**

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 85d6aea0-7903-41d4-8f5a-efba992e8868
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEBRW1MH1XnKD0WMLl1xtJqLpJSeEpgephGcaRTqzz+FdOAXOnYMTcG46+SpNp79cDoH1vnxPswcpuk5lK9HpHaBe8jMx3ILliCPnDieSamD84H0gz+hMgqRauqjw6jTZ/r+vkF+1AzIKo7JcxlG4IqIFXkoQCQlAsdBqALlQbb3y9aSwv9ZrBCc74x+4b7r8TvagFEbN4O984N7/wRh9AvMV/n4MrESePKjOtks53ACBPTf6c4AuBNrnbOvLCABV10KoDRpHhSC9bxQPbR/gM814+utyvRKEjk5kS0sAtUzcmgVkms/iS5vF70ImiVlWnaA2TO82G34zA9g52rRRxeSdpp+LTwMMNPExCxb1TLgyVGp1ROPfwzK7woXMDvmXaHVfVTbp/hLVCLA3O6x2U7aw==
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1f2f5165-56a1-4df4-a70a-d22869b408ec
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEBJlSHjWdNtHzY3WtGpJW+0IQkoF51Pq+hookKBbc9oGTPsm1h9Nm+Y6BphhgbXzAHDpRoOPc7OSQEBOEYC4l4vjgXmOHHVve6lfQqPcZd3zhdFJzy5ZWgP00WIzurOi55j+EHaFRBS1SEx6Tj6rx4AJ/Nuvri8hmBYctbyQzhZKgIVYdviTXhkxzdWHsZ2zduWHU5AWex3Z+xgH3xTrRPUoO7Bsqun+QHS0lqS93D6TejHnhKGJO3Q5cUJA0Lo0iEF9rND4ha0Ar9hyAGseGwqHjQYr0279x1e5KuVnRip6pj3WBiLW7CjW3+XqRLRFSaquIHMqUwp4HcamTjUNSzMFhtHRPRi1w28+tPQ3bswV6b3YMXFc40NQzHzQVn5y/839+xk00UlIKe9SIh9qYecQ==
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 726b8b47-be1f-4aea-aa30-f24d08361d52
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEBHYsYOYJZJV4dMvzprs2v/r3+SGQoxaEYvIfHpwvHkHpPZ7hIgGfhEpZ8mfSJs7iAKETt5KEuyWTbEvIhijX2SjPOWOXZgkvkZ0yAR/sTnLNng3ZwvP7qsLL50FjBBDgAyRCeN0LMdZJ4LApTdCAaeU+5XOnEgpImBeclp7rzlfONofsyyLl7ifuozfzdWz0PhAsIUqLaQzxzvKbOBBZt6lgVgGGDucuduMpcxugarr71N/IGHt00orJMFRhkorvIoNxp1FFbUzFM0izX8Z5/lghFywbXBafoc8TMGp4L+K7ZPRB/T7NNGUKEtTBydbOk2KoQXfFoshV15LE5zT/NLt9UVHbZsjl1yUofxolqEnH0xpi2KCbJXttImaTK7TXI2CzG1ZK0KdBLCGnaCKW7ZA==
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Id] => ed365b40-d6c7-4e8a-afd1-9489a8e4706a
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEBUW6iS/PXNzxciJL2rikTumcgmbVM+aILQQQ99/XxBgOtV+LY6y1qCcbH1TRqk8hv0wzihN/JUnXxik40eF0xHtwMjiay7uFsuAAhorGIh7376IgqK+pPNpHtTjcABCIalt1C2MiugSgy0D3sxyis0pDz7GuN7oVxfvppVPVpnS/3i59WszsiHhNoNEtW3xAZ9EOY3qIlIEG0caPCKPfEAJf9kAUfTPSB45lUve8sjcDk2EGRp0BiwnJ4SYceQLU4eVc2VRky9znK7iDIbCyzWfopnMrjk5zONTcXIa0KixJXlsOzUUdPETMt5WafXUHc3vrvLb7g3zWEo9+W+NeJ4ODwGKrWlBh75ckdIb7ZuADtstINkgfBwTNMOgox+Z9Qi45iJNb3TvHFEFSZ6BUuuw==
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 48c4f212-1375-40f0-abcc-1247bef9b89d
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEB/xROTQvGFdWzP1tUAt75os/f29QzJ1OdXJzIV/24/MmE0HXJlZwAg4EwbO+OQ8EATvrSxJYeO5Y11WToOcTM194f5AnJ1mL2Ul3Zom3OmeiDEqptUz5NsM9jOPQaf/gaHr0V7++8gCosn2UO5+21DdYy0WfAEL3U1gAgB2z5IN/HPQnXg7h5JyxRE/o7BMWs+doAdk/sl5Y82qp1MRVAS8/t6uVF/JTlaPmaeMfeysMKmOEe+OnSibYX0P+KzOzwfC4GmNDh6wepmsZ1PG9IMoKik0bYa0FxFJfPYO81wEtihEqOVUFj8vv+msSRZ+J+uFNCS7ikdAJMWnL0w7AJfj4jWgK5TcThUmjWa9XY40kcNCv0jEiKQwh9S84koPucwbn9ZqRUvtcOD+xXJJiEuQ==
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 604db975-48da-48ab-bd43-334c67cd8450
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEBdoaZFWmTiFmbG7HrX6RoOLTDb45Fsyo6VEgDZb+x01glh4ewQ12emwzSAXsoodM5jP5NOGsqACFxY1rgUFsKP4S2Qi2pEw80X1BwXfrETTp2axwLlrws9I5YoHXqm+D/tJRlSc6whQqS6S1hRnWYAVaTllDDi+zDvi+3dBnStmgRmF3V3FTc8VJZ6PGdrd4UF3UpMzUylQhQndf/vxnnUI6qXd7IjOSZLwoohr0jYRLUSc4QZrp4T4itFgYF4kVSLtB7HCvUhdWt90zR8n4QW7WbTHfhOxRD9gIelFmzl/ssjS85eZ+ZnIxSZiJnJ13DGGNBo5POOHXqk0MOqC7dYzyaW+NOC/C2pBD2XkjG0fDStftb5KuAo+tjtMfCvJAEOtqAQsRXVb9/MN/zhAEPSA==
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Id] => e8525043-7011-4d2b-965e-a844f21ade81
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEBzJZiFcePez9hVhoUmY4ccH758aIfxwM0QkUmIoPlrvyPJGOsQT9GeSPVCjYhCBVlMikj/VohnfANAS0puVsAxwR8sMxhZhrALg2D2nnY2u40d3ktM7YKLhut/FQLxSw7OEqo3NoW3akQdusuWSYKRkb6aLICYhLfJch2x7BPaUFxB6gM4PkPZj9yeocX8KP2+TMPPmT6lESGmq1TjDIXmw0A+eFIWEOr/5k66wbGhDUArrglqKlhJgI15k8k4f5W11LGEJUPVWazzUoCHhzmXiEB3hvfzlzKRQwhdZqM4YHAVZsqrPfcQth3dpdGW6p8yEaco+yBJ13rNZD7EYGARpzMSK3WEU18zbc33SphPHVPewYgtrqNCFev2L/Wfe3mpEN13FLNbUrU1cFRrd7xSw==
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 30ec6108-e3c3-4348-b449-00775f18e579
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEBOGx1ntCVZUGvNvqmk9IQZTUOXa5XTYYlMQatmWEOX0GKfNSq4P1hOcFWgEAhp3C7hFyaTrV+8w5+r+evw6+A80JV1ZKwlSTCti7riYXz7cJDsU6HXvIwrrzZmCBLc1WH6kR983Hi/H9pHqeaB1nOlRLG6jUiQKlLdAVQHVGIDXqmuALGLMTIOiOIzZmcnqhbKiHVJ53lggi/6CCSLe75ofSrFf/dAZCABi8pkuFceOJdcQ8M3qUuwehR879784cnLDVADq6QeEqB9acxINra/MKOo+YyUP0My+49yRJJhjb1vORy3HV56ZsZGNf8tWHuqBSI1aTpPgCUKVGLlId61LHjXMIYlv6e1myY5imt5RLOLleLTq0vQxGtU1bjL+ixOdzLqC571uOIgyEvLkz47Q==
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 06d0c6a5-d266-4f64-8c1a-fcb12e94d1aa
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEB8d+rJyCEGFfw9zNh4lCS1MNxDC9Zdk6ARJjH7ff9gnZzcwWFvuq5JwsWaItY11dDFWowbzY6Xk1Jg4ii2RvViAqEg86dSfK9N0WstWe4yRYv0thVqSv1BuESymoSnaljcmamh6HfxuFHwkiyYFTtc2oJ3YRrWMlAYaSj8cviZPTLb7Q1zc47UlTfEGdpC4KSQ65mPg4ZutlbZQtEzXRZtwMbNm4tFciKBVpK+5N1NcNTi5S+6Nd4stS14q/a928urssO/Gewh7tDXXndZ3PtCEqGKC18xHHMenY5g2xhZT6NsZxu8+lPX8WMS9HB+lwbZeYBWNu/zqSPop/UXJrXSzHIda3beYl1N11vDAXWnfDS1vYOev4NQkeuOVJd6XJso6hGDo7cb/CEtwzwynw19Q==
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 36563e1b-a4a7-4d65-ad89-d5357d1c06a6
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEB0d//nx/AQGOrERVynoRxtbwaerPNHy6vurGAzJ+S7FMf0X5HS3BGNVkUk57GhssgcAiQ1XJ/8iqaZ3NVlER3OXttgjME2bYz+ji/ermvAZCazmP6DsQSqh7caGxIR1HcsAsXksp3nRefEbqoziBPH15xXyhP45SiE6xLBsiIbvP10JMPmDXbhVRBugMf3lYNrXP55ZKf8O0Nm+DrSmk2mckevwugY0SmiGIjwV5+uOIIoKsen37WU0mnDX883jji4GH+TWyE95wHlzRvSa2OZdMWt4s66tyTyVo3U5Ji/9RyUhceNQJZxyKUf68WBeOiymd1TVwzkiJhdmXb5wSteOcZZX2oH+feyOeOBxPwpKbK05ttBNVdf3IayJQvbtUu4q58dkLDdOnJH+m/MC+vyA==
        )

)
```

**Chunk 2**

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1f2f5165-56a1-4df4-a70a-d22869b408ec
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEByG1UiIz/+Uqlb3R5gkfVqOzNrWPYq8YEc3XluoqYJpVQD13TcpeFAPNU4C0NybzsKtRLLQfsM58dUehrlGP5JmU9H+ROgAGDF5R6qVNyot+dJtRKmUJdmt2A2r6NkiYMg7hgrU4+upRMhTlOAY/Ni5HGOvJbhvR/upHKSVe5gWoabQTG6Puvvg8L/pamET+PcImDxQPgSNzLc9L/8SwhTwYyqdYG4CwhymelqiAtI7siHpyBBmC24JyX6IWL/3pJenI0yBZhREdNsd2hHLcZAWoCrhq4EFsneAgcnm9UWOCuorceCOQHU94trl38z9tbXXbpEjI5ZVWlrhc6Abx6vknegjIdAoR2gLwkvUdSTHkV4QxoFZOKjLoYJBeV2ugaHgJi/52/DdL9HNQoQziwZg==
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 726b8b47-be1f-4aea-aa30-f24d08361d52
            [ReceiptHandle] => AQEBcWCMm29Cic5pJH+1I0ppsiQxjQw9Q0znj26PZ2P1YQqu5tMvTsCX6t63JgoYvxzH34Ss6oXxzuXe8vXiIVoj7kSFiZdBnPVq+tcEoEFnCfBOtg2WQVONWlN5JYulAIewxXbQS2JZJjIu4HWHHzhS0oRw62OMz325/pbcuaW2a1mfU+Zs7bF9eK6AOCl4RJ0VBACSodpNJtlyqOxnS7C6zkuuVERGuQIxhFFTx44pAHzvQ3+WklGkY05QNNdxUaGzvQGhqzlwFiPwhBi6Cg22PgrSwnSt8Aef1azykibngUP035LOi1ig6Tc5jrWFX39MN+UYt6AVBTELxv4uTIi1VFJue8f8mRxJSL4H+YQH0BBy/zxPAJZANK4E066jbxtgffk8ktJcZOGBCUuFeFSrVA==
        )

)
```

**Then Loop through the Entries and making delete action**

```
//loop through and delete one by one
foreach($chunks as $k=>$entry_chunk){

    $result = $this->Sqs->deleteMessageBatch([
        'Entries' => $entry_chunk,
        'QueueUrl' => $queueUrl
    ]);
}
```

This deletes the 1st Chunks (of 10 items) while 2nd comes into, it give me error

> AWS.SimpleQueueService.TooManyEntriesInBatchRequest (client): Maximum
>   number of entries per request are 10. You have sent 12.

How I can delete multiple messages at a time?

Comment: How is this connected to [tag:batch-file]??

Comment: sorry, Removed the batch file tag, not related to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$chunks = array_chunk($entries, 10, true);
```

That third argument seems wrong, because of this, in the second chunk:

```
 [10] => Array
```

The 0th element of the second chunk shouldn't have index 10, should it?  Should be 0.  That seems to imply there are 10 undefined elements preceding it, so you're still apparently trying to delete 12 messages in one batch... 10 invalid, undefined ones and the 2 remaining ones.  Because of this error, SQS may not be getting around to telling you that the first 10 messages don't even make sense, because you've exceeded the maximum messages per request -- which is 10 -- and the request is therefore already invalid.

The third argument `$preserve_keys` is set to `true`, but should be `false`.

> **preserve_keys**
>
> When set to `TRUE` keys will be preserved. Default is `FALSE` which will reindex the chunk numerically
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: I already tried this, means `Key preserving = false` still same error

Comment: does calling `deleteMessageBatch()` method in loop, consider new object in each iteration ? means My code is correct or not ?

Comment: your suggestion somehow worked, but now the problem is, eg: I have `36` messages and it manages in `4 chunks`, So, when I loop each chunk, sometime it deletes `15` messages sometime `19` means it not deleting all chunks.

Comment: Honestly, I don't really use php -- I just googled to see how `array_chunk()` worked, and it seemed as if you were doing it wrong.  Dumping and examining the values of $k, $entry_chunk, and $result *should* help you identify why it is still not working the way you expect.

Comment: can you refer this question to any Known person ? I am also not able to find any help regarding this issue. 
the confusing thing is, some time it deletes some of items from 2nd chunk while looping.

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment, if you will properly capture and examine the contents of those variables, you should be able to identify the reason for what you are seeing.  I am not a representative of Amazon Web Services, so referring the question is not something I can assist with. Additionally, Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a code debugging or consulting service.